# How to avoid "no module named _winreg" issue with Google Cloud SDK and Python API on Windows?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform

When starting a local development server with Google Cloud SDK and Python under Windows, an error is thrown when trying to load "platform.py", as this module is trying to import "_winreg". Apprently, this is due to sandboxing of the app engine:

> _winreg is a library for accessing Windows Registry services. It's available in your Python shell since you're running on a Windows machine, but it will not be available when you upload your application to App Engine production servers - therefore, it is also not available in the development server. [[reference]](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/UgFbrFuplsE)

How can I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the variables loaded with _winreg aren't used by the App Engine, I could comment out the relevant section in `platform.py`:

```
# Emulation using _winreg (added in Python 2.0) and
# sys.getwindowsversion() (added in Python 2.3)
GetVersionEx = sys.getwindowsversion
'''
import _winreg
RegQueryValueEx = _winreg.QueryValueEx
RegOpenKeyEx = _winreg.OpenKeyEx
RegCloseKey = _winreg.CloseKey
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = _winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
'''
VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS = 1
VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT = 2
VER_NT_WORKSTATION = 1
VER_NT_SERVER = 3
REG_SZ = 1
```

This doesn't seem to affect the App Engine, and it removes the error!